# Changing parts of SVG-Path on the fly

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael

I'm using RaphaelJS for SVG graphics and I've a path like this:

```
var path = canvas.path("M50,100 l0,100 c100,-100, 200,100, 300,0");
```

But later I might want to change some parts of the graph. E.g:

```
var path = canvas.path("M50,100 l0,100 c100,100, 200,-100, 300,0");
```

Notice the moveTo and lineTo commands are the same solely two arguments for curveTo have changed.
Can I change parts of `path` directly or do I have to draw a new path and delete the old one?

([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SktmU/4/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dBqya/

```
function togglePath(path){
    path.attr('path', 'M50,100 l0,100 c100,100, 200,-100, 300,0');
}

var canvas = Raphael('canvas', 500, 500);

var path = canvas.path('M50,100 l0,100 c100,-100, 200,100, 300,0');
path.attr({ stroke: 'red', 'stroke-width': 3 });

document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function () { 
  togglePath(path);
});
​
```

Comment: I was late with the answer only for a moment. +1 for the right solution.

Comment: Just so.  @yoshi: Don't forget that you can animate the `path` attribute over time as well, morphing one path smoothly into another.  This works especially work if the paths are structurally similar =)

Comment: @KevinNielsen Thanks for pointing this out. In my situation I want to control the animation by myself (with a parameter `t in [0;1]`. Doesn't make so much sense in this example, though :3

Comment: Depends entirely on your desired aesthetic.  In togglePath, try using `path.animate( { path: 'M50,100 l0,100 c100,100,200,-100,300,0' }, 350, '<>' );` instead of `path.attr`.  It will look all sparkly-like.